# JSON Serialization in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, json, serialization, swift

How can I serialize JSON in swift? I am trying to serialize using this method, however it is causing **EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION**. For downloading JSON data, I am using NSURLConnection.

```
var sJson : NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(nsMutData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
```

How can I solve it?

Regards

Comment: Do you mean deserialisation of the data? `JSONObjectWithData` will turn your `NSMutableData` object into an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`, so that's a deserialisation process. Your code fragment looks valid as well - it worked for me.

Comment: Try catching the error: `var error: NSError?' then pass in `&error` as the last parameter to `JSONObjectWithData`

Comment: @Bill did that but still the same problem

Comment: @rickerbh my server returns me this data: [{"0":"Saleem Anwar","FullName":"Saleem Anwar","1":"DHQ:Hospital, ","PlaceOfCurrentPosting":"DHQ:Hospital, ","2":"Dental Surgeon","Nomenclature":"Dental Surgeon","distance":58.415098441417,"lat_dest":"34.1905283","long_dest":"78.0457054"},{"0":"Sartaj Ali Shah","FullName":"Sartaj Ali Shah","1":"DHQ:Hospital, Swabi","PlaceOfCurrentPosting":"DHQ:Hospital, Swabi","2":"Dental Surgeon","Nomenclature":"Dental Surgeon","distance":105.26937892754,"lat_dest":"34.1236046","long_dest":"78.4718982"}]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your root-level data is an *array* of dictionaries -- not a dictionary; therefore replace your line with:

```
var sJson = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(nsMutData, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray
```

I tested it and it now works with your data.

Here's how I tested it after having created a "json.txt" file in my project:

```
var filePath  = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("json", ofType:"txt")
var nsMutData = NSData(contentsOfFile:filePath)
var sJson     = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(nsMutData, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray
```

Comment: Awesome man. I couldn't find such an obvious error. You Sir are genius

Answer (score 3):

This is the swift 2.0 way

```
    let path : String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jsonDict", ofType: "JSON")!;
        let data : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)!;
        var jsonDictionary : NSDictionary
        do {
             jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as! NSDictionary
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4+, JSON Serialization is best done by utilizing the [`Decodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) and [`Encodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable) protocols.

- [Apple docs about encoding/decoding (or serializing/deserializing)
  custom types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)
- Download sample code from Apple on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types)

There is also a detailed tutorial by Ray Wenderlich: [Encoding and Decoding in Swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3418439-encoding-and-decoding-in-swift)

Comment: You sure about that ?